# How to create an efficient static hash table?

Tags: hashtable, data-oriented-design

I need to create small-mid sized static hash tables from it. Typically, those will have 5-100 entries. When the hash table is created, all keys hashes are known up-front (i.e. the keys are already hashes.) Currently, I create a HashMap, which is I sort the keys so I get O(log n) lookup which 3-5 lookups on average for the sizes I care. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) claims that a simple hash table with chaining will result in 3 lookups on average for a full table, so that's not yet worth the trouble for me (i.e. taking hash%n as the first entry and doing the chaining.) Given that I know all hashes up-front, it seems to be that there should be an easy way to get a fast, static perfect hash -- but I couldn't find a good pointer how. I.e. amortized O(1) access with no (little?) additional overhead. How should I implement such a static table?

Memory usage is important, so the less I need to store, the better.

Edit: Notice that it's fine if I have have to resolve one collision or so manually. I.e. if I could do some chaining which on average has direct access and worst-case 3 indirections for instance, that's fine. It's not that I need a perfect hash.

Comment: What's a perfect hash for you? One with no collisions?

Comment: It's perfect if I can guarantee O(1) access. Notice that the data is already hashed using a non-perfect but reasonably good hash, so I'd like to use that instead of hashing again (unless I can store a perfect hash with very little overhead.) Oh and the hashes are already unique, so there are no collisions -- the collisions only happen because I'm doing the hash -> table index mapping.

Comment: @Marc - the term "perfect hash" has a [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). With no evidence to the contrary, I'd assume that OP has that in mind.

Comment: Do you really need a hash table for 5-100 entries?

Comment: To improve the standard design you'l need some extra data that will compensate for those extra few calculations generalized hash table does. Do you have some concrete data about the hash values ? like range ? or do you have them in advance (precompile)?

Comment: @Yochai: They are 32-bit hashes right now (possibly, they will be 64bit in the future.) They use the full 32-bit range. I have them available when the hash table is about to get constructed at run-time, but not at compile time.

Comment: @D.Shawley: It would be a nice bonus if I get the table working instead of the current O(log n) access, as I assume that some of the 100-element tables might get hammered (i.e. 1-10M requests for 3-4 elements), so having 2-3 instead of 7 lookups starts to matter.

Comment: so if only 5% of the elements get most of the hits, it becomes a question of how to maximize the efficiency on the most used elements

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer to err on the side of safety and just have a nice worst-case bound (for instance, at most 3 additional lookups but no wasted storage.)

Answer (score 4):

For c or c++ you  can use [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)

> GNU gperf is a perfect hash function generator. For a given list of strings, it produces a hash function and hash table, in form of C or C++ code, for looking up a value depending on the input string. The hash function is perfect, which means that the hash table has no collisions, and the hash table lookup needs a single string comparison only.
>
> GNU gperf is highly customizable. There are options for generating C or C++ code, for emitting switch statements or nested ifs instead of a hash table, and for tuning the algorithm employed by gperf.

Answer (score 3):

Small hashes are also possible in C without an external lib using the pre-processor, for example:

```
swich (hash_string(*p))
{
case HASH_S16("test"):
    ...
    break;
case HASH_S256("An example with a long text!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"):
    ...
    break;
}
```

Have a look for the code @ http://www.heeden.nl/statichashc.htm

Comment: you misspelled sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sux4j](http://sux4j.dsi.unimi.it/) to generate a minimal perfect hash in Java or C++. (I'm not sure you are using Java, but you mentioned HashMap, so I'm assuming.) For C, you can use the [cmph](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) library.